# Binding c++ static libraries to a project in MonoDevelop under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, monodevelop, xamarin.android

MonoDroid newbie here

I want to use a static c++ library in my Android application written under MonoDroid (It's static because I want to port it to MonoTouch later on). I'm using MonoDevelop under Windows and couldn't find a tutorial explaining how I should compile and link such a library. I'm  now trying to use PInvoke using the SWIG toolkit to bind it to MonoDroid, and need to know e.g. which compiler I should use for the c++ library, where should I deploy the resulting lib file so that MonoDroid could use it etc.
Could anyone direct me to something helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use the same `.a` file between iOS and Android, for a variety of reasons:

- Android is ELF, iOS is Mach-O
- Android code will need to be compiled as Position Independent Code (`-fPIC`), as it'll eventually be in a `.so`, while iOS will not have that requirement (afaik).
- They may have different ABI calling conventions, etc.

You will need to recompile your source for each target platform.

Given that you'll need to recompile anyway, there is minimal point in creating a `.a` file for Android; just create a `.so`. See `docs/ANDROID-MK.html` within the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html).

You can also look at the [SanityTests](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/SanityTests) sample, which uses the Android NDK `ndk-build` command to generate shared libraries:

- The [SanityTests.csproj](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/SanityTests/SanityTests.csproj) [BuildNativeLibs target](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/SanityTests/SanityTests.csproj#L86) invokes `ndk-build`.
- `ndk-build` invokes [Android.mk](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/SanityTests/jni/Android.mk) to generate e.g. `libs\armeabi\libfoo.so`.
- The [AndroidNativeLibrary](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/build_process#Native_Library_Support) build action bundles the native libraries into the resulting `.apk`.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. However, I'm in a very preliminary stage in my application development, and just wanted a simple tutorial explaining for instance which compiler I should use to compile the c++ library (right now I'm trying VC++ 2010), where I should put the resulting lib in MonoDevelop, what method should I use (Miguel de Icaza recommended me the SWIG toolkit and PInvoke). I'll edit my question so it's more coherent..

Comment: Also, I understand from your answer that the deployment to Android and iOS is different, but can I still use the same logic to bind a static library (it's important for code management reasons), or should I change my code?

Comment: You can't use VC++ to generate your static or dynamic libraries; VC++ generates PE/COFF output, which only runs on Windows, not Android (ELF) or iOS (Mach-O). For iOS, you should use gcc/Xcode/etc. For Android, you should use the NDK (http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html) and add the `.so`s to your project (http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/build_process#Native_Library_Support)

Comment: As for "the same logic", as long as your C++ code has an `extern "C"` API, you can continue to use P/Invoke as normal on it. One wrinkle: on Android you specify the shared library name, as normal (`[DllImport("LibName")]...`). On iOS, you instead need to use a library name of "__Internal": `[DllImport("__Internal")]...`: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/linking_native_libraries#Static_Libraries